# For loop to skip certain iterations that are set withing its code

Tags: python, loops

I want to make a for loop to run through a certain array that i dont know its components, i want it so that if in the for loop a certain condition is met the for loop would "continue" a certain number of times without executing the in-loop code before it continues to do so.

The continue command is not a good solution for me because i do not know (and can not know) the exact numbers that i want the for to skip

```py
for i in range(0,y):
    if x == z:
        continue # I want it to execute continue x*z times in a row
```

Currently the code would continue once and then execute the for loop again however i would wish it to skip the loop a certain number of times (like x*z for that matter) (x, y and z are not related)

Comment: that would not make any sense if `x` (as shown) is upper bound and `z` is int value (> 0). `x = 3; z= 3; for i in range(0, x): if x == z: skip x * z` - going out of loop

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest true, i will edit it to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could hack something together like this:

```
skip=0
for i in range(0,x):
    if skip > 0:
        skip -= 1
        continue
    if x == z:
        skip += x*z - 1
        continue
```

Answer (score 2):

You may just switch to `while` loop:

demo sample:

```
i, j, x, z = 0, 15, 0, 3

while i < j:
    print(i)
    i += 1
    x = i
    if x == z:
        i += x*z
        continue
```

The output:

```
0
1
2
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `next` operator on an iterator in this case:

```py
# the iter method will change this into an iterator
# which can be exhausted, like a generator
some_iterator = iter(range(1000))
some_condition = 15

for i in some_iterator:
    if i == some_condition:
        for x in range(some_condition):
            try:
                _ = next(some_iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                break
    else:
        # rest of code
```

Where you can change your `if i == 15` condition, and the iterator will be consumed by `next`. The `StopIteration` is in case the iterator is consumed before the end of the `for` loop. There's probably a more pythonic solution, but that might be where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like a controller variable to check when to continue:

```py
noOfTimesToContinue=0
for i in range(0,x):
    if (noOfTimesToContinue>0):
        noOfTimesToContinue-=1
        continue
    if x == z:
        noOfTimesToContinue=x*z
```